# SQL Server insert of multiple records, of which consists of one field of multiple records from another table, and one static value

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have an ASP.net site connecting to a SQL Server database. In the database, I have 3 tables (among others) that I need to accomplish something.

There are 2 content tables and 1 table that records associations. Here is an example of the tables:

Table: Users

```
UsersIndex | Username     | FirstName | MiddleInitial | LastName
-----------+--------------+-----------+---------------+-----------
92         | MilliVAnilli | Milli     | V             | Anilli
96         | BobLSmith    | Bob       | L             | Smith
...
...
```

Table: Systems

```
SysIndex | SysName   | .... | ....
---------+-----------+------+------
178      | Computer1 | .... | ....
219      | Computer2 | .... | ....
226      | Computer3 | .... | ....
...
...
```

Table: UsersSystemsAssoc

```
UsersSystemsAssocID | UsersID | SysID
--------------------+---------+--------
1                   | 92      | 178
2                   | 92      | 226
3                   | 96      | 178
4                   | 96      | 219
...
...
```

What I need is a all-in-one SQL statement that populates the `UsersSystemsAssoc` table with potentially multiple records from the "Systems" table along with one particular record from the `Users` table. In the statement, there will be one variable provided for the `UsersID`.

For example, if I want to have ALL of the systems in the `Systems` table (but the `SysIndex`, not the `SysName`) populated along with one particular user (JaneMDoe - but using the UsersIndex 125, not the other fields), then I want the result to be this:

Table: UsersSystemsAssoc

```
UsersSystemsAssocID | UsersID | SysID
--------------------+---------+---------
5                   | 125     | 178       <- New record
6                   | 125     | 219       <- New record
7                   | 125     | 226       <- New record
...
...
```

So, here there is a new record in the `UsersSystemsAssoc` table for EVERY record in the `Systems` table, but that record inserts the `SysIndex` of each record along with the same `UsersID` in each of those records.

From the code perspective, there should never be existing records in the `UsersSystemsAssoc` table that will conflict with this insert so the SQL statement does not need to consider this.

I've tried a few things like:

```
insert into UserSystemsAssoc (UsersID, SysID) 
values ((select SysIndex from Systems), (select UsersIndex from Users where Username = 'JaneMDoe'))
```

...but of course, this doesn't work.

Doing something like

```
Insert into <table> (<field1>,<field2>) 
    select <field1>, <field2> 
    from <table2>
```

...doesn't work either since the insert is not all from the same one table.....

I am unsure what syntax is appropriate for this.

Thanks.

Comment: This question makes no sense at all. Can you try to explain what you are trying to do here? Start by posting the ddl for the three tables. Then an explanation of the process you trying to achieve.

Comment: I'm not sure what I can add from an explanation perspective other than posted that would help. The SQL statement is being executed with a button click within an ASPX page, with codebehind that updates a SQL database. I would be able to do a "select SysIndex from Systems" and run a foreach through all the records found to do individual SQL insert statements into the "UserSystemsAssoc" table but that sounds pretty costly. If that's really the only way to do it, then fine. But I imagine there must be a better way from within SQL so I only have to do one connection / statement.

Comment: Like I said...start with posting the table definition. I don't understand the process here. Are you inserting a new row into the first table and you want to copy all the details from the other tables along with the userid for the newly added row or something? You certainly don't want or need to use a loop for this kind of thing.

Comment: Described from another perspective. I have systems in a table and Users in a table. I want to "assign" all the systems to a particular user. The "UserSystemsAssoc" will need one record for each System containing the User (by index) in question and the System (by index).  The existing site displays and manages this information already. The only thing I'm adding is a "Associate all systems to current user" kind of capability.

Comment: The only table in which I want records added is the "UserSystemsAssoc" table.

Comment: I don't have table definitions with the above tables as they're pseudocode. (I cannot post specifics from the actual system). All 3 tables have an IDENTITY index.

Comment: There is no table structure that can really be a trade secret....but you could post even psuedotables that represent the issue. That way the people who are volunteering time to help you don't have to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is still not really clear what you are trying to do so here is a shot in the dark. I am guessing that you want something like this.

```
declare @UserID int = ? --TheValueFromTheFrontEnd


insert UsersSystemAssoc
(
    UsersID
    , SysID
)
select @UserID
    , SysIndex
from Systems
```

Comment: This is exactly what was needed. I wasn't familiar with declaring variables within SQL. Thx.